# MySQL result in PHP by ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can i display something out of my databse by an ID number?

I already can get the data out of the database by searching the row 'content' but i want to get it by an ID number.

I have three rows in my database table: ID, pagename and content.

Here is the code that i already have for getting the data:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","jordyyd108_mario","testdb","jordyyd108_mario");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['content'] ;
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: ever heard of `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `WHERE` clause and pass your id try

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE ID = '2'");
```

or pass a variable

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE ID = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can by using WHERE :-

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages where id = 1");
```

Comment: again the same way? :)

Comment: No, worries. I am deleting the answer. I dont want any issues now :)